# WP 3.3.1 Cant get jQuery Datepicker to work

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

at first i want to tell that i **HAVE** read the post:

**jQuery UI Datepicker not working**

already.
I followed the instructions, but stll, i cant get it work.

I am using WP 3.3.1 with the standard theme twentyeleven.
There are 2 other jQueries running: "jExpand.js" and "sorttable.js"
Thats it. very plain.

In the functions i added this:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wp33r01_date_picker' );

function wp33r01_date_picker() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');   
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery.ui.theme', get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/' . '/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css');
}
```

which generates this in the DOM (footer):

```
<script src="http://sge.cashier-software.com/js/jExpand.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="http://sge.cashier-software.com/js/js_script.js" type="text/javascript">
<link id="jquery.ui.theme-css" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://sge.cashier-software.com//css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css?ver=3.3.1" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://sge.cashier-software.com/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.dev.js?ver=20111130" type="text/javascript">
<script src="http://sge.cashier-software.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js?ver=1.8.16" type="text/javascript">
<script src="http://sge.cashier-software.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js?ver=1.8.16" type="text/javascript">
```

Then i have on Document ready these lines:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // $("#atcs tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    jQuery("#atcs tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    jQuery("#atcs tr:first-child").show();

    jQuery("#atcs tr.odd").click(function(){
        $(this).next("tr").toggle('slow');
        $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
     });
    jQuery('tr.detail_row').css({'display':'table-row'});

    //$("#atcs").jExpand();    

    jQuery('#date_from').datepicker();

});
```

And finally, the simple Form in which i wanted the Datepicker to work:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
   <input type="​text" id="​date_from" name="​sge_date_from">
   <input type="submit" name="sge_submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

But it simply does **NOTHING** :(

I hope my description works, so might somebody can help.

Many thanks in advance,

Joe

Comment: Check your CSS enqueue. This can't be right: "sge.cashier-software.com//css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css?ver=3.3.1". I'm pretty sure all jQuery UI widgets need at least some CSS in order to work properly. If you want the includes folder, use includes_url() instead of get_bloginfo('wpurl').

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. You are right, the 2 "//" wasnt ok. But that didnt change nothing. And, i do  not want the includes folder. The css is in the right folder and the enqueue gets the right file. So, sorry, but still no prgogress :(

Comment: check if you have other jQuery in the header .. you might be loading two different versions .. if so - you need to deqeue one .

Answer (score 1):

CSS needs to be in the head of the document. Use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook instead. Also be sure to only enqueue the scripts and styles on screens where you need them.

Comment: Definitely right, the only and right way. The datepicker works in 3.3.1, I used in the plugin wp maintenance mode.

Comment: @helenhousandi, thanks for your Answer. I changed the css to the header. But still no improvement :( . Ans, why should i use the admin_enqueue_scripts? The datepicker should run in the frontend. I am not a Wp professional so i might understand things wrong. Lucky to see that at least someone got it running already ;)

Comment: If this is on the front, then use `wp_enqueue_scripts`.